# JHtml Tabs have no IDs - how can I specify them?

Tags: jquery, jhtml

Using the below code, I can successfully create the tabs that I need, however, the Tabs do not contain any IDs for specific styling or jQuery work.

There are a *variable number of tabs*, depending on User Group,etc., and most of them are updated on some interval with new information.  Updating the content of each Pane is not a problem as they *do* have IDs, but addressing the relevant tab to alert the user of the new info is the problem.

Can the `$options` array contain specifications for IDs to be generated?

```
// Start Tabs
echo '<div class="tabbable tabs-left">';
echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.startTabSet', 'tab_group_ida', $options);
// Tab 1
echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.addTab', 'tab_group_ida', 'tabs_1a', 'Tab 1');
echo '<p>Pri putant iisque detracto ut.</p>';
echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.endTab');
// Tab 2
echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.addTab', 'tab_group_ida', 'tabs_2a', 'Tab 2');
echo '<p>Duo delectus vivendum id, sit.</p>';
echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.endTab');
// Tab 3
echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.addTab', 'tab_group_ida', 'tabs_3a', 'Tab 3');
echo '<p>Tamquam constituam an qui, ea.</p>';
echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.endTab');
// End Tabs
echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.endTabSet');
echo '</div>';
```

**Firebug view of the tabs:**
[image: Firebug view]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Just use an attribute selector.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) You can target the href attribute in css with [href="#tabs_1a"] for example. I have no experience with jQuery, but the example in GDPs answer uses attribute selectors to add ids, so I'd guess jQuery supports this.

The bottom line is that you do not really need to add anything, just use attribute selectors to target something already existing, in your case href.

Sometimes :nth-child is a viable alternative.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source code of the page, you'll see that Joomla is using jQuery to append the LI and A elements at runtime.
You can use the same technique to add IDs, Classes, CSS, or any other attributes that you may need.

Use this jQuery code to add a prefix to the tab's name, then add the ID attribute to the anchor.

**Note:** Insure the code is run *after* Joomla creates the tabs, otherwise they won't yet exist to operate on.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var idPrefix = 'myId-';
    $("#tab_group_idaTabs li").each(function(li) {
        var a = $(this).children().first("a");
        var tabname = a.attr('href').replace('#','');
        a.attr('id',idPrefix + tabname);
    });
});
```

Comment: Please, don't set inline css styles though. That's not cool.

Comment: True, it's there only to demonstrate a supported jQuery method

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  });` << Use this to wrap around your jQuery code, rather than using `(function($){` and then `$(document).ready(function() {`. @Seth is right, you should only need to use jQuery to add your classes and the rest can be done with pure CSS.

Comment: Point taken on the CSS, lol....was just a random attribute to demonstrate.

Comment: Also be sure to make `$('a[href="#tabs_1a"]')` and the other objects a variable if you're using them more than once, just as you have with the first tab :)

Comment: Again, most emphatically, the variations were simply to demonstrate.  The script wrapping was based on the way Joomla does it for each of the tabs, so chose to keep that intact.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to add ico-moon icons to a tab and you could wrap the a in a tag:

```
    // Tab 2
echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.addTab', 'tab_group_ida', 'tabs_2a', '<i class="icon-info"><i>'.Tab 2');
```

so you could also wrap it in a span:

```
<?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.addTab', 'ID-Tabs-Group', 'tab2_id', '<span class="icon-signup">'.JText::_('DESCRIPTION').'</span>'); ?>
```